# How do I force this submit button to a new line using CSS?

Tags: css

I want the button forced to the left and on a new line. The only way I've been able to accomplish this so far is by inserting some extra markup, `<br /><br /><br />`, above the markup for the submit button.

How do I modify this CSS to force the button onto a new line?

```
fieldset input[type="submit"] {
    background-color: #d3dce0;
    border: 1px solid #787878;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 1.0em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display : inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot of what the form currently looks like would help?

Comment: Show us the HTML where are you submit button, it is necessary

Comment: HTML is needed. At least a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 5):

In your CSS, please change this line:

```
fieldset input[type="submit"] {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to this way:

```
fieldset input[type="submit"] {
    display: block;
}
```

And no spaces after `display` please. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, display: block; didn't work. It shifted the elements located to left of the submit button downward slightly and kept the button on the same line.

Comment: @user1469655 Give a class to the submit button like `class="block"` and in the CSS, give `.block {display: block;}`. It should work!